# Correctly Mounting NTFS partition on Linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, backup, ntfs, rsync

So a brief overview of what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm currently running (an almost fresh install) of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a test hard drive. I also have a Windows 7 partition on the same drive. My main goal is to have a shared NTFS partition between both OS's. I will be performing backups of this shared partition through rsync to a separate backup drive formatted to NTFS, which will contain all of my documents/files from either OS unrelated to the root or C:/ drive. This is a single-user personal setup, so permissions and other security measures aren't as critical as a typical case with multiple users and an administrator.

Through some experimentation and research I've come up with a mount option as such:

```
sudo mount /[sharedPartition] -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /[sharedPartitionDestination]
sudo mount /[backupDrive] -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000 /[backupDestination]

sudo rsync -rltDvu --modify-window=1 --progress /[source]/ /[destination]
```

(rsync command courtesy of [HOWTO: Backup using Rsync to NTFS](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820425))

I want to ask the community for some input on the syntax used above. Like I mentioned the permissions are not a huge concern especially as the data will be going to an NTFS formatted drive. My main concern is that all data will be read/written without issue from all of my source directories when performing the backups. So far, I haven't run into any trouble accessing the data.

To test a variety of file formats at once I copied (through rsync) a couple of games (Starcraft, World of Warcraft) from my Linux partition directly to the backup drive and launched both games without issue on Windows 7. I did the same once more with the shared NTFS partition as the source. If I ran into any problems, I figured they'd be most likely detected right away as either game would have trouble reading files necessary for playing. (playing back various audio files, loading images etc... from either directory went seamlessly as well).

Am I OK to proceed with the syntax as listed above for actual long-term use? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you're syncing from NTFS to NTFS, and you're running the script as root, there's no reason to use the `-o uid=1000,gid=1000` syntax. Everything else looks good.

Comment: The reason I'm including the gid= and uid= parameters is because it seems I am unable to delete files and directories when browsing the mounted drive through the file manager. I just tried mounting it again having omitted those options to confirm. Only way to get around that was to run the file manager (nautilus in this case) as root, and I avoid doing that cause we all know that can be quite dangerous. Otherwise I'd agree if I was just doing things through the terminal. So it's really a thing for convenience sake. Thanks for your assurance though, seems like I can go on with this method.

Comment: Ahh..I was only looking at the ramifications of the backup.